# Distribute integral over a summation in sympy

Tags: python, math, algebra, sympy, integral

I have the following code:

```
a2 = Rational(1, alpha2)*integrate(phi2*wx12, (x,-1,1))
```

The result is:

```
  1                     
  ⌠                     
  ⎮  ⎛ 2   1⎞           
5⋅⎮  ⎜x  - ─⎟⋅wx₁₂(x) dx
  ⎮  ⎝     3⎠           
  ⌡                     
  -1                    
────────────────────────
           2
```

Now I want to distribute the integral to obtain this:

```
                       1            
  1                    ⌠            
  ⌠                    ⎮  wx₁₂(x)   
  ⎮   2              5⋅⎮  ─────── dx
5⋅⎮  x ⋅wx₁₂(x) dx     ⎮     3      
  ⌡                    ⌡            
  -1                   -1           
────────────────── - ───────────────
        2                   2
```

Anyone knows how to do this?
Using `a2.expand()` only expands the inner expression of the integral.

Comment: It was not easy to get into this thread :-)

Comment: Why? The title isn't descriptive enough?

Comment: Just go to the [main page](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sympy) and try to click on your thread :-)

Comment: I didn't see anything special ...

Comment: On FireFox one can not enter your thread by clicking on it's header.

Comment: I'm using Firefox 23 on Ubuntu.
Maybe it will better to use only ascii characters. Or if you can post pictures, you could add this images: http://krhps.dyndns.org/static/f1.png http://krhps.dyndns.org/static/f2.png

Comment: Yes, FF23.  But it seems to be a problem only on Windows.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There isn't a function in SymPy to do this directly ([yet](https://code.google.com/p/sympy/issues/detail?id=2297)), but it's not hard to do it yourself.

The easiest way would be to just do it manually. If you know what the integral is, you can replace it using subs.

That way is annoying if you don't know what the integral is, and you don't want to type it out. A better way, which is not particularly general, would be

```
a, b = symbols('a b', cls=Wild)
expr.replace(Integral(a + b, x), Integral(a, x) + Integral(b, x))
```

This only splits an integral in two, so if you want to split by more than that, you will need to make it more general, or else apply it multiple times. And if the integral is with respect to a different variable, you'll need to change that.

For a more general version, we can use an underdocumented feature in SymPy, the `Transform` object (in fact, the documentation isn't even in Sphinx, I have to point you to the [source code](https://github.com/sympy/sympy/blob/master/sympy/core/rules.py#L8) for more information):

```
from sympy.core.rules import Transform
def split(integ):
    return Add(*[integ.func(term, *integ.args[1:]) for term in Add.make_args(integ.args[0])])
expr.xreplace(Transform(split, lambda i: isinstance(i, Integral))
```

`Transform` creates an object that converts expressions into other expressions using a rule. The rule here is `split`, which decomposes an integral using `.args` and splits it up over an addition using `Add.make_args`, and then creates new integrals using the remaining arguments (which are the variables and limits of integration).  The `lambda i: isinstance(i, Integral)` tells the `Transform` to only apply to Integral objects. `Transform` returns an object that is suitable to pass in to `xreplace`, which does a replacement.

Here's an example

```
In [20]: expr
Out[20]:
⌠
⎮ ⎛ 2        ⎞
⎮ ⎝x  + x + 1⎠ dx + 3
⌡

In [21]: expr.xreplace(Transform(split, lambda i: isinstance(i, Integral)))
Out[21]:
                  ⌠
⌠        ⌠        ⎮  2
⎮ 1 dx + ⎮ x dx + ⎮ x  dx + 3
⌡        ⌡        ⌡
```

Comment: Thanks @asmeurer! I finally did it manually, despite they were many integrals :) . The Transform object seems very useful.